# I don't know how to resolve this nextLine thing and make it work

Tags: java

```
    do {
        System.out.println("write in format \"firstname lastname\"");
            
        //just want to scan a sentence with spaces
        String[] tempArr = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            
        System.out.println("Hello " + tempArr[0]);

        System.out.println("Do you want to do it again Y/N");

    }while(sc.next().equals("Y"));
```

I don't know to how to prevent the nextline scanner to scan the blank after first iteration

I want the loop to run until anything other than "Y" is being entered

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `do...while` loop for this. You could easily do this by making an infinite loop that stops if the answer is not "Y". I am assuming that you want to loop on user input `Y` and stop on anything else. If it's the opposite, just flip the boolean in the if statement. Try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("write in format \"firstname lastname\"");
            String[] tempArr = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            System.out.println("Hello " + tempArr[0]);
            System.out.println("Do you want to do it again Y/N");
            String answer = sc.nextLine();
            if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know the other ways to achieve the functionality, but I'm just wondering that why my code is not working or how to make it work.